# how do I remove specific data points that are outliers or have high leverage on my regression model?

Tags: r, regression, outliers

I have created this plot using ***ols_plot_resid_lev()*** and have seen outliers and leverage points and i want to remove these to improve my regression model. My data set has 5 variables all with 140 bits of data each. I made this plot by doing:

```r
model <- log(variable) ~ variable2 + variable3 + variable4 + variable5
rmodel<- lm(model, data = dataset)

ols_plot_resid_lev(rmodel)
```

outliers and leverage plot:

[image: outliers and leverage plot]

You can see there are points with numbers and I have seen a video where they access these datapoints and remove them but my data is not as simple as theirs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2OSemc72sM around 1:40

I have tried doing what they do in the video:

```
lm.sm[35,1]
```

But it gives me this error:

> Error: object 'lm.sm' not found

Any ideas of how I can take out these data points?

UPDATE:
here is the improved graph:

[image: improved leverage and influence points plot]

after using cooks and hat functions it improved. Is it possible to fully remove all leverage and influence points?

Comment: In principle, you can put the whole process inside a `while` loop so that it will keep successively removing outliers and high-leverage points. I have two general comments: (1) rather than edit your question to reflect information you got from the answers, you should post a new question; (2) in general I would **not recommend** automatic removal of outliers and high-leverage points, especially not recursively (but of course what you do with your models is your business ...)